# data inserted as 0 into table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

For some reason, when I insert the data from the form, it inserts 0 into tables with attributes "title" and "contains". I have set both the attributes as `VARCHAR`.
Following is the function to add data into table "data1".

```
function add_record($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('data1', $data); 
        //return;
    }
```

Following is the function where I am creating an array to post the data and passing that array into `add_record()` method. 
Also, I have autoloaded site_model file so I believe I don't have to load the model here.

```
function create()
    {
        $data=array(
            'title'=>  $this->input->post('title'),
            'contains'=>  $this->input->post('contains')
        );  
        $this->site_model->add_record($data);
        $this->index(); 
    }
```

Anybody, ,please let me know!!

Comment: Did you check what $data contains.Try var_dumb($data) or print_r($data)

Comment: In your `add_record` function try to `var_dump($data)` so you can be sure.

Comment: Hey Deepu, Thank you for prompt reply. Actually, it was an error while setting up a base_url in config. Now, its working good:). I usually use var_dump($data) as a debugging technique, but I am very new to this ci. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thankx Sheikh Heera, Its working fine now. This stakcoverflow is really great!!

Answer (score 2):

Wrong data type in database can be a reason also.